# JavaScript comma separation not working with switch case

Tags: javascript

In case of comma separation not working with swtich case. is there any way to do this?

```
switch(test)
{
   case 0,1://not working it take last one (1)
      "test"
      break;
   case 2,3://not working it take last one (3)
      "test2"
      break;
   case 4,5://not working it take last one (5)
      "test3"
      break;
}
```

How can i add further number with each case?

Comment: Also you could use `if (that === 0 || that === 1) { ... } else if ( ... ) { ...`.

Comment: Or `"test" + (Math.floor(test/2) ? (Math.floor(test/2) + 1) : "")` would also bring the same result :-D

Comment: It works in Go but not in JS. But IntelliJ adds a warning "Comma expression"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should fall through (which is considered  a bad practice)

```
switch(test)
{
    case 0:
    case 1://not working it take last one (1)
      "test"
      break;
    case 2:
    case 3://not working it take last one (3)
      "test2"
      break;

}
```

Comment: In this case it is clearly visible where and why you fall through, so it isn't a bad practice. It would be considered a bad practice if there were commands after `case 0`, **then** you'd fall through into `case 1` and it wouldn't be clear whether the `break;` is or isn't supposed to be there. Then it is appropriate to leave a comment like `/* falling through */`.

Comment: @Imp yes actually i agree with you, but this wouldn't pass jslint validation.

Answer (score 7):

```
switch(test)
{
   case 0: case 1:
      "test"
      break;
   case 2: case 3:
      "test2"
      break;
   case 4: case 5:
      "test3"
      break;
}
```

Comment: The syntax shown here feels the most self-explanatory, in terms of self-representation for future developers.